# Javascript to execute code from .cs?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, button, event-handling

I have a search.aspx page, with which I want to do the following:

If the user closes this page(browser), I want to trigger some code frome the .cs. I have a script which is called on page close: `HandleClose().` I can prompt an alert if I close the page, so I know the function `HandleClose()` is called. Now I want to execute to a method from the .cs (logout the user). I tried using the `.click()` on a button, which then would execute the code from the .cs.

I tried using "`document.getElementById("buttonname").click()`" in `HandleClose(),` but this doesnt work, it looks like the `OnClick` event isnt triggerd. Any idea how I can execute my code from the `HandleClose()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make an asynchronous call to the code behind, probably using something like JQuery.

Baring that you could open a new window when the page is closed, do some code on Page_Load and then close this page after you've done what you need to do.

You can open a new page using [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ajax with asp.net web methods](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx) to achieve what you are trying to do, but the page close event what ever you are trying is quite unreliable as the browser may not even give you enough time to fire the javascript in case of power failure or system error or something like that